# How to accept data in the state from two bot users Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram, fsm, aiogram

The task is to receive one photo each from two users, make a record in the database with these users and photos. When I open a state I receive a photo from the first user, and then I need to open a state for another user and receive a photo for him in the same state machine. How can this be realized?
**IMPORTANT: Aiogram 3.x!**

I tried to create separate instances of FSMContext class, but I couldn't process them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.